# Getting TLE in CodeChef and need for improvement of code

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a practice question of **CodeChef** . In this problem we are given N numbers A<sub>i</sub>...A<sub>n</sub> and we first have to sort(ascending order) the numbers and then add the alternate numbers starting from the last and show the output for each test cases , the test cases has 2 parts :
1>Constraints :
 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000

2>Constraints:
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>
You can see the full problem [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFA/).
The first part of my problem was **successfully submitted** but second part showed **NZEC** because I was using `long` to add those numbers(which was beyond that range). So I decided to use Strings to add up my numbers here is the method :

```
public static String myStringWayToAdd(String first , String second){
    String temp = "";
    if(first.length() < second.length()){
     temp = first;
     first = second;
     second = temp;
    }
     temp = "";
     int carry = 0;
     for(int i=1;i<=first.length();++i){
        if(i <= second.length()){
          carry += Integer.parseInt(first.charAt(first.length()-i)+"") + Integer.parseInt(second.charAt(second.length()-i)+"");
        }
        else{
         carry += Integer.parseInt(first.charAt(first.length()-i)+"");
        }
     temp += carry%10;
     carry = carry/10;
     }
     if(carry != 0)
     temp += carry;
     StringBuilder myResult = new StringBuilder(temp);
    return(myResult.reverse().toString());
 }
```

But now it shows **TLE(Time Limit Expire)** , So then I thought to use BigInteger(which I am not pretty much Aware of but I saw some tutorials) :

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("0");
big = big.add(BigInteger.valueOf(mySort.get(j)));  //for addition and mySort is my ArrayList
```

But this **gave me NZEC** I don't know why
well now I want to use `double` variable but there is a **problem with that too**, because with double large numbers will be in form of **exponential** value like :
`1.243536E15` which will **not be** accepted by the machine, so is there any good way to **solve** this problem and not getting any Time Limit Expiry?.
Any help will really be appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

---

**Edit 1 :**
I changed baxck the variable to long and run and this time strangely I got **TLE** here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.lang.Number;
class CFEA{
  public static void main(String[] s){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<testCases;++i){
     long sum = 0;
     //BigInteger big = new BigInteger("0");
     ArrayList<Integer> mySort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     int n = scan.nextInt();
      for(int j = 1 ; j <= n ; ++j){
       mySort.add(scan.nextInt());
      }
     Collections.sort(mySort);
      for(int j = mySort.size()-1 ; j >= 0 ; j=j-2){
         sum += mySort.get(j);
      }
     System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is [Link](http://www.codechef.com/submit/complete/598160-9195--542d8b2b83c8d) to my submission.Is there Anything I can optimize in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in my Program and it was **All Accepted** a much relief after submitting for about 20 times , here is my new code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
class CFEA{
  public static void main(String[] s){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    byte testCases = Byte.parseByte(scan.nextLine());   //used byte for test cases instead of int
    for(int i = 0 ; i<testCases;++i){
     long sum = 0;
     //BigInteger big = new BigInteger("0");
     ArrayList<Integer> mySort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
     String input = scan.nextLine();
     String[] my = input.split(" ");
      for(String myString : my){
       mySort.add(Integer.parseInt(myString));
      }
     Collections.sort(mySort);
      for(int j = mySort.size()-1 ; j >= 0 ; j=j-2){
         sum += mySort.get(j);
      }
     System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

I think the main villain was that I was scanning for Integers N number of times as in this :

```
for(int j = 1 ; j <= n ; ++j){
       mySort.add(scan.nextInt()); 
      }
```

When N was something Like 100000 then this really slows it down.So i used 1 String for complete line and then Split it into Integers using `split` method as in :

```
String input = scan.nextLine();  //only 1 Scanner
     String[] my = input.split(" ");
      for(String myString : my){
       mySort.add(Integer.parseInt(myString));
      }
```

Although My code got submitted I still think there is Further scope for optimization , so please do answer if you have something better

Answer (score 1):

1. The sum of all number is at most `10^9 * 10^5 = 10^14`. It is small enough to fit into `long`. There is no need to use `BigInteger`.
2. `java.util.Scanner` has performance issues. You can implement a custom scanner(using `BufferedReader`) to speed up your code.

Here is my implementation of a scanner:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FastScanner {
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    public FastScanner(InputStream inputStream) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    }

    public String next() throws IOException {
        while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                throw new IOException();
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    public int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So my problem is something else maybe

Comment: @NawedShaikh Yes, it is not about `long` overflow.

Comment: Strange this time I am getting TLE for long as well

Comment: @NawedShaikh There can be two problems: 1. Arrays.sort(if you use it) uses quick sort and can have `O(n^2)` running time on a specially constructed test case. 2. I/O can be too slow if you use `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: So what should I use Instead?. BufferedReader?

Comment: Can you explain a bit how to implement Custom Scanner through BufferedReader

Comment: @NawedShaikh I have added my scanner implementation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you +1 for your precious time :)...this will help me in future